# Solr - Error while inserting solrj as dependency in POM

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, solr, solrj

I need to connect to Solr with SolrJ. I imported the library in POM in this way:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

When I try to connect in localhost, I've no problem.

```
public class SolrJSearcher {

    public String solrSearch() throws SolrServerException, IOException {
        String collection = "Users";
        SolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient.Builder("http://localhost:8983/solr/" + collection).build();
        SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
        query.setQuery("*:*");
        query.setRows(1);
        QueryResponse response = client.query(query);
        SolrDocumentList results = response.getResults();
        String returnValue = JSONUtil.toJSON(results);
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

When I change the hostname from "localhost" to prod environment, I can't connect. The strangest thing is that, during deployment, I get the following error even if I remove the above method altogether and leave only the dependency in the pom.
What can this be due to? Do I need to enter some configuration to make it not automatically connect to localhost?

```
    2022-11-21 17:09:31.013+0100 WARN [org.springframework.boot.actuate.solr.SolrHealthIndicator] (http-nio-8080-exec-1) [anonymousUser/NONE/d145ccb7-4dfe-4acd-8b6a-b924900d621d] Solr health check failed
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: Server refused connection at: http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr 
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:672)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:265)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:248)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:211)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:228)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.solr.SolrHealthIndicator$RootStatusCheck.getStatus(SolrHealthIndicator.java:115)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.solr.SolrHealthIndicator.initializeStatusCheck(SolrHealthIndicator.java:78)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.solr.SolrHealthIndicator.initializeStatusCheck(SolrHealthIndicator.java:66)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.solr.SolrHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(SolrHealthIndicator.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator.getHealth(HealthIndicator.java:37)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.getHealth(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:85)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.getHealth(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:44)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:99)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getAggregateHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:110)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:61)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.health(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:71)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.health(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:77)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.AbstractDiscoveredOperation.invoke(AbstractDiscoveredOperation.java:60)
    at
```

Comment: you have hardcoded the url in code with localhost and hence its the error... does you java application and solr server on the same machine in production...Ideally should not be...Extract the server details to properties file and use it java code

Comment: and if you are using springboot for your application then it should be very easy to read the properties for your application

Comment: My java app and Solr Server are not on the same machine. How could I estabilish a connection between them if not hardcoding the endopoint of Solr Server in HTTPSolrClient? Is there another way?

Comment: if you are using springboot then please refer this https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring

Comment: So, according to you, only removing the string from the class and setting it in the properties file would resolve the problem?